# Jruby installation with rvm giving java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rvm, jruby

I am trying to install jruby on my jenkins server. This is what is happening.

```
 $rvm install jruby
    Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
    jruby-1.7.3 - #configure
    jruby-1.7.3 - #download
    jruby-1.7.3 - #validate archive
    jruby-1.7.3 - #extract
    jruby-1.7.3 - #validate binary
    jruby-1.7.3 - #setup
    RubyBasicObject.java:1250:in `setVariableStamped': java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun/misc/Unsafe.putOrderedObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V
        from RubyBasicObject.java:1211:in `setVariableInternal'
        from RubyBasicObject.java:1204:in `setVariable'
        from RubyClass.java:265:in `set'
        from RubyBasicObject.java:1371:in `variableTableStore'
        from RubyBasicObject.java:1439:in `setInternalVariable'
        from RubyStruct.java:219:in `newInstance'
        from Ruby.java:1371:in `initCore'
        from Ruby.java:1213:in `bootstrap'
        from Ruby.java:1148:in `init'
        from Ruby.java:286:in `newInstance'
        from Main.java:262:in `internalRun'
        from Main.java:221:in `run'
        from Main.java:201:in `main'
    Saving wrappers to '/srv/jenkins/home/.rvm/bin'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rvm install jruby --disable-binary
```

If you find any more details open a ticket for RVM => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/

Comment: it can not behave the same, `--disable-binary` changes the route in RVM and instead of just unpacking  binary it downloads sources and runs an `ant` build, something has to be different.

Comment: Please check this http://pastebin.com/aF9Fj8m6 .. i first removed jruby and reinstalled ur way..